# How to call `e.stopPropagation()` for the `onClick` event with the `react-select` component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

I have a component that performs an action when you click anywhere on it, unless you click on certain children components which have there own `onClick` handlers. Those `onClick` handlers are able to prevent their parent from doing its standard action, by calling `e.stopPropagation`. How do I similarly capture and `stopPropagation()` on the `ReactSelect` component's `onClick` event? The normal `onClick` handler never gets called.

This is basically the setup as described (ES6):

```
handleMost = e => { 
  // Note that I cannot check e.target here, because there is a bunch
  // of other stuff that might be the target that still should cause
  // the standard action to occur 
  doStandardThing();
}

handleFoo = e => { e.stopPropagation(); doSomethingFoo(); }}
handleBar = e => { e.stopPropagation(); doSomethingBar(); }}
handleBaz = e => { e.stopPropagation(); doSomethingBaz(); }}

<ListItem onClick={handleMost}>
  <Foo onClick={handleFoo}
  <Bar onClick={handleBar}
  <ReactSelect ?????={handleBaz}

  <OtherStuff ...>
</ListItem>
```

Comment: Would you please set one working example in codepen or in webpackbin?

Comment: try `onChange` attribute

Comment: @maioman , the `onChange` attribute returns the changed value as the first argument, not the associated click event

Answer (score 8):

I took a look at all the events from react-select, but seems that it doesn't fit your purpose.

I suppose as a workaround you can try to wrap the `ReactSelect` component in another element.

```
<span onClick={e => ....}>
  <ReactSelect />
</span>
```

Comment: But if I call `e.stopPropagation()` on the `span`'s click then wont that stop propagation to the <ReactSelect /> component as well?